# which solution is the right one?

Tags: analysis

Let $0<x_{1}<1$ and $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_{n}} $.Show that $(x_{n})$ is decreasing.Find the limit of $x_{n}$ and the limit of $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$.
I showed that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}$=$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x_{n}}}$ ,that is smaller or equal to $1$,so the sequence is decreasing.
Then I supposed that $x_{n} \to l \in R$.From $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_{n}} $ we find that $l=0$ or $l=1$.But,how can I accept one solution and reject the other one?Or can I find the limit in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the fact that $0\lt x_1\lt 1$, and the fact that the sequence is **decreasing** $(l\lt \cdots < x_3 \lt x_2 \lt x_1 \lt 1)$ to show that the limit therefore cannot be $1$, and hence, the limit must then be $0$, given the possibilities that $l = 1 \lor l = 0$.

Comment: Could I also say that the sequence is decreasing and bounded from below,so it converges to its inf??

Comment: Yes, indeed you can!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing and $0<x_1<1$, you have $x_n<x_1<1$ for all $n$. In particular the limit must be $\le x_1$.

Comment: Could I also say that the sequence is decreasing and bounded from below,so it converges to its inf??

Comment: Yes, you can say that.